# Gradle build with Error:Cause: tried to access method

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am getting following error when trying to build gradle android project.

> Error:Cause: tried to access method
>   com.android.build.gradle.internal.model.AaptOptionsImpl.create(Lcom/android/builder/model/AaptOptions;)Lcom/android/builder/model/AaptOptions;
>   from class com.android.build.gradle.internal.model.ModelBuilder

My project structure looks as follows:

```
project
|- app
|-- build.gradle (#1)
|
|- module1
|-- build.gradle (#2)
|-- app_module_1
|--- build.gradle (#3)
|-- lib_module_1
|--- build.gradle (#4)
|
|- build.gradle (#5)
|- settings.gradle
```

The main app uses the lib_module_1 of the internal app. The internal app_module_1 can be build seperately using the module `build.gradle (#2)` settings.

When trying to build the main app defined in `build.gradle (#1)` i get the problem. Deleting the `build.gradle (#2)` fixes the problem, but then I can't build the `app_module_1`.

`app_module_1` is not defined in the outer `settings.gradle`.

I am using `build tools 23.0.2`, `gradle 2.9` and gradle `build plugin 1.5.0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change somenthing in your structure.

In your `project/settings.gradle` you have to include all modules.
If you need the `app_module_1` you have to specify it in the `settings.gradle.`

If you want to build separately the `module1` the only way is to add the tasks or the variables defined in the `build.gradle (#2)` also in the `build.gradle (#5)` or to use the command `apply from` inside the `build.gradle (#3)` and `build.gradle (#4)`.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to read the question and answer. I'll check it tomorrow at work.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work for me. My app module uses `'android-reporting'` which has to be used in the top level `build.gradle`. I have solved it by putting the file into an dedicated folder inside one of the modules and copying it before executing gradle on jenkins.